# Cluster Performance

Tags: performance, cluster-computing

Cluster Performance 
I have a client who has 2-web server which are clustered. Two questions...

1. What data makes up the statistics or information you would use to be able to monitor performance or load?
2. Once you have this data identified, how do you know it is time to add a third server?

Comment: Perhaps a better question for serverfault.com ?

Answer (score 0):

Uou... no simple question:

- OS memory and CPU statistics
- JVM heap size, CPU usage, GC frecuency
- Balancer logs, session replication stas, bandwith usage

And so on...

It is time to add a 3 server when 2 are well configured and they can not keep up to the expected QoS.

Regards.

Comment: aaahh YES, good old QoS! What if there is no QoS currently established with your end users. From a strictly hardware performance side, what would some thresholds be to establish that this cluster is getting worked over and it is time to add a 3rd server?

Comment: I see, you want a general solution you can apply in every situation no matter the requirements, the load, the scalability... thanks god yet expertise and knowledge is required.